# How to detect outside click on bootstrap modal in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

Requirement is i want to detect if the user has click outside the modal here is my modal code

```
<div class="modal fade modal-metadata-list">
<div class="modal-dialog" id="my-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header sys-version-header">
            <img class="modal-resultPage pull-right" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" src="../images/Cancel.png">
            // Modal Content 
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

and i am calling the modal in this way

```
<a style="text-align: center" ng-click="showMetadataModal(reprintDocument.docId)">
```

Comment: can i ask why you need this? Is it to prevent the modal from closing when clicking outside?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the modal does not take up the whole screen, in which case, you can use the outer element to check if the user clicks.

```
jQuery(outerElement).on('click', function(){
    //your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply i tried that, The thing is that i want to detect the event when user click outside and the modal is closed. basically if u specify the outerElement it will still trigger that same event when you click on modal itself.

Comment: Theoretically, if you add a z-index to the modal itself, then when you click on the modal, it will not trigger the click function. If you have more code available (or can create a js fiddle, then I can get a better understanding of your code.